# Typeahead.js does not return anything

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to set up the twitter typeahead (based on this https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/examples/#remote) to load results from an sql query but it does not work.
This is my code:

```
<head>
<script src="resources/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="resources/typeahead.bundle.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="search" type="text" placeholder="blabla">

<script>
var search = new Bloodhound({
  datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('value'),
  queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
  remote: {
    url: 'search.php/?key=%QUERY',
    wildcard: '%QUERY'
  }
});

$('#search').typeahead(null, {
  name: 'typehead',
  display: 'value',
  minLength: 3,
  highlight: true,
  source: search
});
</script>
</body>
```

All I have in my search.php for now (for testing purposes) is:

```
<?php
$key = array("display this");
echo json_encode($key);
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so turning $key into an array, solved this, now "display this" gets passed back to the script (according to firebug). The problem is now that the drop down doesn't display. I don't want to make a new question just for this, hopefully somebody can enlighten me here what's wrong with the dropdown. :)